# D language: Iterate over members of a struct and check a UDA (runtime reflection)

Tags: reflection, d

In D language, I want to iterate over a structure and perform logic specific to each annotation attached to each member. Ex.

```
struct Pattern {
    string pattern;
}

string Max {
    int max;
}

string Min {
    int min;
}

struct StructToValidate {
    @Pattern("^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$")
    string phone;

    @Max(20)
    @Min(3)
    int someValue;
}
```

and then in a function, do something like this:

```
int main() {
    StructToValidate struct;

    // begin pseudocode
    // for each member of struct mem = [phone, someValue] {
    //     if (hasUDA!(mem, Pattern)) {
    //         do stuff like validation on the runtime value of this member
    //     } else if (hasUDA!(mem, Min)) {
    //         ...
    //     } else if (hasUDA!(mem, Max)) {
    //         ...
    //     }
    // }
    //
    return 0;
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it. If it's a struct, I'd go with `__traits(allMembers, T)`, but for classes I'd go with `__traits(derivedMembers, T)` to make sure you don't get garbage from object inheritance or from other instances you aren't interested in (In cases where you want from inhertiance allMembers would work too).

For a generic case where it might be either a struct or a class, but you aren't sure, I'd go with `derivedMembers` for safety.

What you should do though is to use `__traits(compiles)` to guard against private members, because `allMembers` and `derivedMembers` will also return privates etc.

See: https://dlang.org/spec/traits.html#compiles

I'd probably do something like this:

```
void validate(T)(T toValidate) {
    import std.traits;

    foreach (member; __traits(allMembers, T)) { // Loops through all members of "T"
        static if(__traits(compiles, __traits(getMember, T, member))) { // Guards against private members
            static if (mixin("hasUDA!(" ~ T.stringof ~ "." ~ member ~ ", Pattern)")) { // Checks if the member has the UDA "Pattern"
                // TODO: pattern
            }

            static if (mixin("hasUDA!(" ~ T.stringof ~ "." ~ member ~ ", Min)")) { // Checks if the member has the UDA "Min"
                // Gets the value from the UDA and stores it in a variable that we can use at runtime.
                auto value = getUDAs!(mixin(T.stringof ~ "." ~ member), Min)[0].min;

                // Creates an assert for validating the member's value.
                mixin("assert(toValidate." ~ member ~ " >= value);");
            }

            static if (mixin("hasUDA!(" ~ T.stringof ~ "." ~ member ~ ", Max)")) { // Checks if the member has the UDA "Max"
                // Gets the value from the UDA and stores it in a variable that we can use at runtime.
                auto value = getUDAs!(mixin(T.stringof ~ "." ~ member), Max)[0].max;

                // Creates an assert for validating the member's value.
                mixin("assert(toValidate." ~ member ~ " <= value);");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
int main() {
    StructToValidate structToValidate;

    validate(structToValidate);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I didn't implement pattern.

Although you could use:

https://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html

Comment: Wow that is clever. Mixin magic never ceases to amaze me. I will try this when I have more time.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer :) But yeah string mixins are amazing and let's you do pretty much anything

Comment: Worked like a charm. The only adjustment I had to make was removing the elses, so that multiple attributes on a member would all be processed.